# HTML Form is double submitting! How to stop it?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action="/login" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="loginForm" onsubmit="return login();">
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="User Name" required /><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required /><br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="passwordHash" id="passwordHash"/>
    <input type="submit" id="loginButton" value="Log in" />
    <!--other fields-->
</form>

<script>
    function login(){
        var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        if(userName && userName.length > 0 && password && password.length > 0) {
            var hashObj = new jsSHA(password, "TEXT");
            password = hashObj.getHash("SHA-512", "HEX", 1).toUpperCase();
            document.getElementById("userName").value = userName.toLowerCase();
            document.getElementById("password").value = "";
            document.getElementById("passwordHash").value = password;
            document.getElementById("loginButton").disabled = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

When I check the server logs, this code is double submitting the form. Causing the first submission to pass, and the 2nd one to fail the CAPTCHA and other checks.

What is wrong with this code and how do I prevent double submission?

Comment: "Do some stuff" seems to be interesting. If you are submitting in there, don't. If you are ajaxing in there, return false/preventDefault. If you return false, then you need `onsubmit="return login();"`

Comment: Nah. It just clears the password field and sets a hidden field with the hashed password.

Comment: Is the page called login? Could it be resubmitting when reloading?

Comment: Resubmit when reload? I don't get it. The URI is `/`.

Comment: How can we know? Very little details in your question. Could it be a plug-in that interferes? Either browser plugin or some framework manipulating your code - form processor or pretty form

Comment: also don’t clear the fields obsubmit, they won’t be sent

Comment: I don't want the password to be sent. I want the password hash to be sent.

Comment: So what do you do to create and send that Hash? Why do I have to pull every little detail out of you to help you with your question?

Comment: Sorry. The `passwordHash` is a separate field.

Comment: 1: disable or hide the submit button in the login function. 2: do NOT call submit in the login function

Comment: Updated. `submit` is not called in login function. disabling the submit button does not help...

Comment: Change the button type to `button` not `submit`, on its on click call the function and the call `form.submit()`.

Comment: That is not necessary, @AmirPashazadeh

Comment: always sending the password hash and never the original, effectively makes the password hash become the password. So you need to re-hash it server side...

Answer (score 0):

use mybutton.disabled=true; . it'll fix your problem:

< form method="POST" action="..." onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;">

Comment: Well, that fixed the double submission part, but the server does not receive the hidden fields.

Comment: this method just disabled the button when you click it for the first time. did you write : onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; return true;login();   ???

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: try this out:
onsubmit="myButton.disabled = true; login(); return true;
or: onsubmit="myButton.disabled = login();true;  return true;

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the function. Also you need to include jsSHA AND you need to call it correctly:

Change hash back to hidden when tested

```js
function myLogin() {
  var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  if (userName.trim().length == 0 || password.trim().length == 0) {
    return false; // stop submission
  }
  var hashObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
  hashObj.update(password);
  document.getElementById("passwordHash").value = hashObj.getHash("HEX").toUpperCase();
  document.getElementById("userName").value = userName.toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("password").value = "";
  document.getElementById("loginButton").disabled = true;
  return true; // allow submission
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsSHA/2.3.1/sha.js"></script>
<form action="/login" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="loginForm" onsubmit="return myLogin();">
  <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" placeholder="User Name" required /><br/>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="passwordHash" id="passwordHash" />
  <input type="submit" id="loginButton" value="Log in" />
  <!--other fields-->
</form>
```